# Cyclotomic Polynomial Recurrence Identity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, cyclotomic-polynomials

> If p is prime, show that $\Phi_{p}(x^{p^{k-1}})=\Phi_{p^{k}}(x)$.

I have the solution, however I cannot make sense of how the author got to it. I understand the need to use the fact that p^k and n are coprime if and only if p and n are coprime, however the rest of the details are vague to me. I apologise for my formatting if I messed it up. Thank you

http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/earl/complex/0163.pdf  - Intended Solution (would appreciate it if someone could explain it)

Answer (score 1):

The number of coprimes is given by the [euler totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function) which says the number of coprimes is $\phi(p^n)=p^n-p^{n-1}$ whenever $p$ is prime so what is seems to me the proof is doing is something like

$\Phi_p(x)=\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}\Rightarrow \Phi_p(x^{p^{n-1}})=\frac{x^{p^n}-1}{x^{p^{n-1}}-1}$

$\Phi_{p^1}(x)=\prod_{k,\gcd(k,p^1)=1}(x-\omega_k)=\prod_{k=1}^{\phi(p)}(x-\omega_k)=\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(x-\omega_k)=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^p(x-\omega_k)}{\prod_{k=1}^1(x-\omega_k)}=\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}=\Phi_p(x)$

$\Phi_{p^n}(x)=\prod_{k,\gcd(k,p^n)=1}(x-\omega_k)=\prod_{k=1}^{\phi(p^n)}(x-\omega_k)=\prod_{k=1}^{p^n-p^{n-1}}(x-\omega_k)=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{p^n}(x-\omega_k)}{\prod_{k=1}^{p^{n-1}}(x-\omega_k)}=\frac{x^{p^n}-1}{x^{p^{n-1}}-1}=\Phi_p(x^{p^{n-1}})$

---

From exploring this problem I think the proof goes this way to avoid proving it as is appears to be more commonly done but which is maybe a little more complicated, something along the lines

Take/proof the identity

$\Phi_n(x)=\frac{x^n-1}{\prod_{d|n}\Phi_d(x)}$

Which for $n=p^n$ implies

$\Phi_{p^{n}}(x)=\frac{x^{p^{n}}-1}{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\Phi_{p^{k}}(x)}\quad (d|p^n\Rightarrow d=p^k,\ k<n)$

and then proceed inductively

$\Phi_{p^{0}}(x)=x^{p^{0}}-1=x-1=\Phi_1(x)$

$\Phi_{p^1}(x)=\frac{x^{p^{1}}-1}{\prod_{k=0}^{0}\Phi_{p^{k}}(x)}=\frac{x^{p^{1}}-1}{\Phi_{p^{0}}(x)}=\frac{x^{p^{1}}-1}{x-1}=\Phi_{p}(x^{p^0})$

$\Phi_{p^2}(x)=\frac{x^{p^{2}}-1}{\prod_{k=0}^{1}\Phi_{p^{k}}(x)}=\frac{x^{p^{2}}-1}{\Phi_{p^{0}}(x)\Phi_{p^{1}}(x)}=\frac{x^{p^{2}}-1}{x^{p^{1}}-1}=\Phi_{p}(x^{p^1})$

and so on

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to convey the solution as presented in the author's one. I think only thing that would be a little unintuitive to me is why totient(p^n) = p^n - p^(n-1). But thats not a problem since I can easily look at a derivation and understand why.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to convey the solution as presented in the author's one. I think only thing that would be a little unintuitive to me is why totient(p^n) = p^n - p^(n-1). But thats not a problem since I can easily look at a derivation and understand why.                                                                                                                                 EDIT: The formula is now intuitive to me. I think the author assumed the line of reasoning behind that identity is obvious to the reader

Comment: @Integrable I'm glad it helped, the Euler totient is an interesting function so it could be the author is going to introduce it later, if useful another argument why it works is contained in one of the section to the Wikipedia article from the link, if you know it for the primes you know it for all the number since $\phi(n)= \phi({p_1}^{k_1} \cdots {p_r}^{k_r})=\phi({p_1}^{k_1})\cdots\phi({p_r}^{k_r})$